# SQL table structures and query

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am developing mobile app which is very similar to Handy or Homejoy and struggling to set database scheme for this system.

I am very newbie to sql, using mysql and innodb as engine.

Basically user can make reservation regularly or one time.
One time reservation is easy for me. just see requested date and time if it has free cleaners and return the available cleaners.

But the thing is harder when user wants regular bookings.
In regular booking there are some rules.

**rules**

> 1. There are 3 options that user can choose (4 / 1 month(every week), 2 / 1 month (biweekly), 1 / month (once a month) )
> 2. Reservation is for 3 months (If user choose every week option in 7/9/2015, this reservation is end to 10/9/2015)
> 3. Regular reservation matches one customer to one cleaner.
> 4. User can edit upcoming single reservation. (Time, additional stuff)    If possible, rescheduling to the cleaner who the user is already
>      connected. If not, then any other available cleaner.
> 5. Cleaner can upload their unavailable time
> 6. If user select Monday as first starting cleaning day, rest of the cleaning days are also Monday at same time.

So what I want to do is making a APIs that return available date and time that the user can choose when making a reservation request. Once user select one of the available dates and times, then a list of available cleaners at that time will be shown and then choose one of them.

Here's my table below

**Master**

```
'CREATE TABLE `masters` (
`id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` char(128) NOT NULL,
`image` blob,
`phone` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`push_key` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`dateofreg` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`email`),
UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
KEY `master_id` (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

**User**

```
'CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`gender` int(11) DEFAULT ''0'',
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`salt` char(128) NOT NULL,
`access_token` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
`phone` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`dateofbirth` date DEFAULT NULL,
`dateofreg` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`email`),
UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

**Bookings**

```
'CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`master_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`booking_group` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`additional_task` bit(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`day_of_week` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT ''0'',
`date` date NOT NULL,
`start_time` time NOT NULL,
`end_time` time NOT NULL,
`status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `user_id_idx` (`user_id`),
KEY `start_time_idx` (`start_time`) USING BTREE,
KEY `end_time_idx` (`end_time`) USING BTREE,
KEY `bookings.master_id` (`master_id`),
CONSTRAINT `bookings.master_id` FOREIGN KEY (`master_id`) REFERENCES     `masters` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `bookings.user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES   `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

I think only with these tables it is hard to find first available date from tomorrow to 3 months

Can you help me making tables and queries which return first available date and time based on that table in 3 months?

Comment: Do you want an API or queries?

Comment: select id from masters m
                            where not exists (            
                                select 1 from bookings bs
                                    where m.id = bs.master_id and ( 
                                    start_time between SUBTIME(%s, '00:59:00') and ADDTIME(%s, '00:59:00')  or
                                    end_time between SUBTIME(%s, '00:59:00') and ADDTIME(%s, '00:59:00')
                                )
                            )

Comment: This query is what I tried in while loop. I ran this query for about 3 months duration.

Comment: This is quite slow and not a good solution I guess. I want query and table structures